# how to separate multiple values with comma while fetching from form

Tags: php, jquery

I fetch the records from form(i.e from dynamic table) and trying to store in variable, but face a problem that both values are not separated by comma so trouble to store that values.
Here is my code:

```
 var skill_f = $("#table_display_skills tr").find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
 var importanceSkill_f = $("#table_display_skills tr").find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();

 var industry_f = $("#table_display_industry tr").find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
 var importanceIndustry_f = $("#table_display_industry tr").find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();

 var education_f = $("#table_display_education tr").find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim();
 var importanceEducation_f = $("#table_display_education tr").find('td:nth-child(2)').text().trim();
```

if my table contains two rows like, 1. java and 2. html so when I store it into variable skill_f, I got value as **javahtml**, and importance as **MandetoryOptional** so I facing problem while storing these two value, so what should i do? How to separate them?
How to store values?

and Like skills parameter, there are other parameters too.

Comment: You can spilt them if there is space between values using split() function

Comment: Provide your sample value set.

Comment: <skills>javahtml</skills><imporatnceSkill>MandetoryOptional</imporatnceSkill> i get this response

Comment: This is xml response you can separate out values by xml parser, see jquery example......https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: I am generating this xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var joinSkill = (elements) => {
  var skills = [];
  elements.each(function() {
    skills.push($(this).text().trim());
  });
  return skills.join(',');
};

var skill_f = joinSkill($("#table_display_skills tr > td:first-child"));

console.log(skill_f);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_display_skills">
  <tr>
    <td>css</td>
    <td>css2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>html</td>
    <td>html2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this one : var skill_f = joinSkill($("#table_display_skills tr")

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if I want data like css | css2, html | html2 then what should i do change in the code to get this type of output.

Comment: change `skills.join(',');` to `skills.join(' | ');`